# crawler test for meta tag - silex phpunit

Tags: phpunit, silex

```
$this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('meta[charset="utf-8"]'));

$this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("meta[charset="utf-8"]")'));
```

all this have failed. How can I test meta tags? I need to check the meta keywords and description for a specific value.

Comment: Where you set this values? in the body of the response or in the header?

Comment: body of response. $client->request('GET', '/'); giv me whole html document including head block.

Comment: check if the html is valid (all tag are closed...) otherwise the crawler don't find anything (try test if a simple expression exist)

Answer (score 0):

I came here cause I had the same problem with the form's element in my page: nothing was filtered by the $crawler

Turned put the problem was the return in my **app.php**, when I finally mage it correctly all the tests worked fine.
I'll copy here my working code (assume my **view.php** is a php file with basic html code)

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/', function() {

    ob_start();
    require __DIR__ . '/path/to/view.php';
    $response = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    return new Response($response);
});

return $app;
```

So, in **web/index.php**, i must require **app.php** and run it:

```
<?php

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/app.php';

$app->run();
```

Finally, in my functional test, I could do the follow:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/path/to/autoload.php';

use Silex\WebTestCase;

class SampleTests extends WebTestCase
{

    public function createApplication()
    {
       return require __DIR__ . '/path/to/app.php';
    }

    public function testSamplePage()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('meta[charset="utf-8"]'));
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is not the best way to do it but it's the only one I figured out.